# Resistor power ratings & Package

Tags: voltage, power, current, ac, three-phase

I have this [circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMkAcAWA7ATjigbGHojFinHkiAnBHAKYC0iiAUAEpIYVYXMBMIHuEo0QAZj55IFCH2hY0YnMT5KxiHGKhx2nXlgH8kB4YioQJUmcLCQdHRFxB8UKJIgEu3EM6MvThBjkwBSU4FTUNOC1bHTQwMz549wExMDQUyhQAHQBnRDg8pkL82Fg8sArIZlcxLgSMDSwMTDw84jLwPL5K0rL%20pAqWeMTknrc0jPGs9pLi9v7epYXO3p6VxZhB3LBhhOdkyfF044yzHPy5go3ynaqeurExNBQMELREND4sG4g13o6mx8QwATnpBBQkhAhD5FiwwVCIQcfC5TLAWABzZFIVGIz4ZP6Y7F8JLE5KErGIiSyQ5iay7MEaQwmPEmWH9eHYpnE0nshnE1zY6lomCcxyQwWIrwisosAoZOluaZoF7OMDecRUKgsADupzVEzwSvV4F1%20qMiuMAl2eqOdqNzl5LAAsiAVca3GghNNZHZdGJ0JlFIYPDY3bQw7FOUcLYGjHzoydpgGzqGE2C7ScU5kEwB7YxIawADxQxEQFAQtjMEDOIAYeC0nxFpmtUGrIAwNmqpqAA) that detects the phase difference between 3 phases.

My questions are,

1. I'd like to know the power ratings and packages of the 1M and 1k resistor.
2. Also, what should be the ratings of the op-amp? Like, what should I take care of while selecting the op-amp?

Also, I am confused about what should I do with the neutral wire that comes as the input. Should I connect to the non-inverting op-amp ground? Or should the op-amp non-inverting ground should be digital ground and neutral doesn't play a role?

Comment: Please don't build this and kill yourself through ignorance of the mains. Those 1 M resistors can have a fairly nominal power rating, but the VOLTAGE and safety ratings they require will not be found in cheap, easily available, resistors. It is a frame error (ie clearly demonstrating a lack of appreciation for the important things involved) to be wondering about the 1 M resistors and the 1 k resistors in the same question. You need isolation components and protection components to do this safely. The falstad circuit is conceptual at best, it is way short of a usable circuit.

Comment: @Neil_UK, thank you very much for the clarification. Can you please help me with a sample circuit that will satisfy the safety conditions as well? Also, if you could let me know the ratings, I will take that into account.